# LDAP compare attributes

Tags: attributes, comparison, ldap

I would like to filter for all LDAP objects where the CN does not equal the sAMAccountName. Therefore I wrote the following query, which unfortunately neither works nor seems to be RFC compliant:

`(!(cn=sAMAccountName))`

Does anybody know how to acheive the desired functionality?

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: The question doesn't appear to make sense as posed. Do you really want to retrieve every record *except* that one? What is your actual requirement?

Comment: As said, I want to retrieve all objects (in my case users) where the Common Name does not equal the sAMAccountName. I thought the query would be (cn!=sAMAccountName) which can be also written as (!(cn=sAMAccountName)) ... But apparently, I am no LDAP expert :)

Comment: No, that just returns all the records where the 'cn' attribute doesn't have a value 'sAMAccountName', taken as a literal. I don't think you can write a filter for what you want. It's only the LHS that is taken as an attribute name.

Comment: Take a look at [Scott Lowe's blog post on using Log Parser to do this](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2006/08/01/complex-queries-against-active-directory/).

Answer (score 2):

LDAP filters do not allow using value of another attribute for filter comparison. You have to fetch the entry and compare both values.

Answer (score 1):

`(!(cn=sAMAccountName))` is "RFC compliant", because the right-hand side of the assertion is taken to be a value of the `cn` attribute.

Using this filter will result in all entries being returned in a search response where value of the `cn` attribute is present, and the matching rule for `cn` returns `false` for the case-insensitive value `samaccountname` (assuming the `cn` attribute matching rule has not been changed from the published standard). The results will be subject to:

- server time limit
- server size limit
- server access controls

Perhaps you meant to use

- `cn=value-of-samaccount-name`

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a Windows environment, you can use PowerShell Expression Language for this.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server my.domain.name -Properties CN |
  Where-Object {$_.CN -ne $_.sAMAccountName}
```

This is a fairly expensive query because it returns every single user object for PowerShell to do processing on, but it does work.