# retrieving specific userlogonid from AD

Tags: powershell, shell, active-directory

I am trying to retrieve all users from AD using PowerShell that have the same SAMaccountname as their employeeid but i am having difficulty trying to get that information. Would anyone be able to assist how i can go about it?

I have tried the below

`Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select GivenName, SAMAccountName and also Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($employee.employeeID)'" -Properties SamaccountName | Export-Csv -Path C:\Support\GDPid.csv -NoTypeInformation`

but this will give me all the users in AD. How do i go about retrieving specific users with SAMaccountname same as their employeeid

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a list of employee id's, or are you referring to where they match on the users accounts? Something like `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmployeeId | ? EmployeeId -EQ SAMAccountName`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala i don't have a list of users, i just wanted to generate the list of users where their employeeid matches the samaccountname and i tried the above but it generates a blank CSV

Comment: Slight tweak to @AbrahamZinala's solution: `Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmployeeId | ?{ $_.EmployeeId -eq $_.SAMAccountName}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pull back everything you want to compare, then perform that comparison on the client side, as LDAP doesn't provide a way to compare attributes with one another on the server side[*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493296/361842).

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties EmployeeId, GivenName | 
    Where-Object { $_.EmployeeId -eq $_.SAMAccountName } |
    Select-Object SAMAccountName, EmployeeId, GivenName |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Support\GDPid.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

### Update 2022-11-19

You'd said you also want to filter out "generic accounts" so you just get "user accounts".  From AD's perspective these are all user accounts (i.e. it's `Get-ADUser`); but from our perspective some accounts are actual employees / people, some are used for shared mailboxes, some are used to run services under, etc.

There doesn't seem to be an [official solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/713108/distinguish-between-users-and-service-accounts-in-active-directory) for this.

I guess you only care about accounts with an employeeId for your scenario / those which aren't people wouldn't have one whilst all those who are would?  If that's the case: `Get-AdUser -Filter "employeeId -notlike '*'"`.

At my company we've used one of the [extensionAttribute#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisesextensionattributes)s to define the different types of accounts; as even within "user" (actual people) accounts there's further options:

- It's the user's main account for day to day stuff / the one we'd send mails about the xmas party to.

  - they're an employee of the company
  - they're a contractor/temp currently paid by us
  - they work for a third party vendor but need an account in our system to collabore with us / access our resources
- It's a user's admin account, so they can access sensitive resources (so if their day-to-day account ran something malicious, that wouldn't have admin access on any servers and thus the impact could be limited).
- It's a copy of the user's account that they use for testing
- etc

So we may do something like `Get-AdUser -Filter "(employeeType -eq 'Permanent') -and (extensionAttribute1 -eq 'User')"` to get our employees' main accounts, or `Get-AdUser -Filter "(employeeType -eq 'Permanent') -and (extensionAttribute1 -like 'User*')"` to fetch employees' accounts, including any admin (`User Elevated`) or test (`User Test`) accounts they may have.  But that's not standard AD; that's a taxonomy we implemented to try to make sense of what we've got in there so we can put rules around it.  The discussions around this stuff can be endless, as you'll find so many edge cases (e.g. I recently integrated our AD with some org chart software; but my manager was technically an external contractor even though I'm permanent - so we needed filters which allowed some contractors to be part of our org chart, whilst others were excluded / seen as third parties).
If you need to have such discussions, get your requirements written down first and use those to drive things; then hunt out the edge cases and use them to drive discussions.

Other common tactics for distinguishing accounts are:

- samaccountname format conventions (e.g. prefixing service accounts with `svc-`, mailboxes with `mail-`, etc).  `Get-AdUser -Filter "samaccountname -like 'usr-*'"` or `Get-AdUser -Filter "(samaccountname -notlike 'svc-*') -and (samaccountname -notlike 'mail-*')` etc.
- Use of OU structure `Get-AdUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Employees,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com'` (note: search base only works for filtering top down; so whether you can use this depeonds on your OU structure; i.e. if you have geographic OUs high up, with a mix of real people and service accounts at each location you can't easily filter for real people at all locations).

Comment: Hi John thank you so much for this. It works well however when i run the above it also retrieves generic user accounts, how do i go about filtering the generic accounts out and only have user accounts? my apologies i should have made it clearer

Comment: Updated - probably more info than you were hoping for, but hopefully some use